# Looping over all files in a folder in R over multiple loops

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop

I have written code that runs sampling functions on a csv files for a biome.
I have 30 csv files that I want to loops these for loops over. I am struggling with applying this code I've written easily across all files in my folder. I'm sure this is an easy fix, I'm just finding issue with the loop inside of a loop.

```
temp <- read.csv("tropical_grassland_N_Am_point_summary_table_gdrive.csv")
temp <- temp[which(temp$nd > 0.1),]


index <- substr(temp[,5],30,(nchar(as.character(temp[,5]))-2))
unique_index <- unique(index)
unique_index <- sample(unique_index, 20, replace=F)
for (i in 1:length(unique_index)){

  temp2 <- temp[which(index==unique_index[i]),]
  theDates = strptime(temp2[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d")
}

thresh <- 0.95

for (i in 1:length(unique_index)){

    temp2 <- temp[which(index==unique_index[i]),]
    theDates = strptime(temp2[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d")
  }
```

All of the csv files have _point_summary_table_gdrive.csv in common after the description of the continent and biome.

Comment: you can start with `list.files(pattern="+csv")` then loop your code through the filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they in the same folder without other files ? if so, if your code works, you don't need to know the file names. just make a function of it and then

```
filenames <- list.files(path = whatyouwant, pattern = "*\\.csv$", all.files = TRUE,full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
files <- lapply(filenames,read.csv)
lapply(files,yourfunction)
```